# Dual Booting Questions

Tags: dual-boot, windows, laptop

I have an Asus s200e laptop running Windows 10, and it has a C and D drive. The D drive is never in use by Windows, so I want to put Linux on it, how do I do so without deleting anything? What should I make sure to do? I am fairly familiar to Linux, just not so much partitions. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you shrink the D drive and free up the space in which you want to install ubuntu, go into device manager - disk management and shrink the D drive, then unallocate the space where you want to install ubuntu & you can safely install linux.
This way you will also have some part of D drive to store data and some part which will be utilized by linux.
But make sure that you leave sufficient space for ubuntu installation.

Good luck Dual booting.

Comment: How about all of the safeboot stuff in windows? How do I disable safeboot etc?

Comment: Well I don't think so you have to do all that...because I think they have removed that feature in win10. I don't know much about that. But through my experience....I use win 10 dual booted with debian. For me it went normally as it would with Windows 7. No safe boot options n all.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to disk management on windows.
2. shrink the volume of the D drive leaving the unallocated space for linux.
3. make bootable linux usb.
4. while installing linux choose largest unallocated space